# Does Black Hole requires a material medium to be formed?

Tags: black-holes, vacuum, matter

Does Black Hole requires Material medium to be formed or it can be formed without any medium (Vacuum)? as anything which can be thrown with the speed of light can form a Black Hole and light can also travel in vacuum .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Is it clear right now ?

Comment: It's still not entirely clear.  Are you asking "can a black hole be formed from light?"  Or "can a black hole be formed without any matter at all?"

Comment: I mean both you got it @MichaelSeifert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John Archibald Wheeler demonstrated [Geon solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geon_(physics)) to Einstein's equation, which involve gravitational waves that form bound states.  Research has shown that those states can collapse into a black hole.  Since, gravitational waves, by definition, have $T_{ab} = 0$, then yes, you can get black holes from vacuum.